# Limit on threads to run

Tags: c, multithreading, function, error-handling, pthreads

I am enqueuing 1000 1's to a queue using different threads and function enqueueThread.

```
for (i = 0; i < num_pthreads; i++)
{
    if ((rc = pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, enqueueThread, (void*)q)))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "error: pthread_create, rc: %d\n", rc);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
}
```

But at the end it prints error: error: pthread_create, rc: 11 which apparently means I dont have enough resources for the threads. I checked it via ulimit -u and it says 128. Does that mean I need to increase this number 128 to something like 10000 as I am trying to run that many threads.

Comment: Why not just not use that many threads?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `setrlimit()` system call with `RLIMIT_NPROC` parameter to define the child thread creation limit. There are two limits, Hard limit and Soft limit. Soft limit can be increased only up to the hard limit, But you need super user permissions to change Hard limit. [See man page](https://linux.die.net/man/2/setrlimit)